# Counting the amount of times a boolean goes from True to False and False to True in a column in presto

Tags: sql, iteration, presto

I have the following table with three columns :
**Id, timestamp , fact**

| ID | Timestamp | Fact |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-25 11:21:12 | false |
| 2 | 2021-10-14 18:49:25 | false |
| 2 | 2021-11-03 12:48:47 | true |
| 2 | 2021-11-08 23:15:12 | false |
| 2 | 2021-11-08 23:15:30 | true |
| 3 | 2021-10-07 04:06:08 | false |
| 3 | 2021-10-07 07:47:43 | true |
| 3 | 2021-10-07 07:49:56 | false |
| 3 | 2021-10-07 07:51:35 | false |
| 8 | 2021-10-06 15:36:46 | false |
| 8 | 2021-10-06 15:37:12 | false |
| 9 | 2021-10-07 07:13:27 | false |
| 9 | 2021-10-07 07:15:07 | true |
| 9 | 2021-10-07 07:17:33 | false |
| 10 | 2021-10-06 14:03:57 | true |
| 10 | 2021-10-06 14:10:45 | false |

I want to write a query which gives me the following outcome:

- per each id , it gives first and last fact value and when they happened
- per each id , how often fact has been changed from True to False or False to True
- per each id, count of fact

Then the outcome would be:

| ID | first_fact | first_iteration | last_fact | last_iteration | chang_in_fact | iterations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | false | 2021-10-25 11:21:12 | false | 2021-10-25 11:21:12 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | false | 2021-10-14 18:49:25 | true | 2021-11-08 23:15:30 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | false | 2021-10-07 04:06:08 | false | 2021-10-07 07:51:35 | 2 | 4 |
| 8 | false | 2021-10-06 15:36:46 | false | 2021-10-06 15:37:12 | 0 | 2 |
| 9 | false | 2021-10-07 07:13:27 | false | 2021-10-07 07:17:33 | 2 | 3 |
| 10 | true | 2021-10-06 14:03:57 | false | 2021-10-06 14:10:45 | 1 | 2 |

How can I do that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? The solution for this is vastly different from mysql and sql server.

Comment: It's sql server

Comment: @Saba why do you have Presto in title and tags if you are using SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

In presto you can use `lag` operator to get previous then use it to compare with "current" and then group everything by id and get needed facts with `max/min_by` :

```sql
WITH dataset(id, Timestamp, Fact) AS (
    values (1, timestamp '2021-10-25 11:21:12', false),
        (2, timestamp '2021-10-14 18:49:25', false),
        (2, timestamp '2021-11-03 12:48:47', true),
        (2, timestamp '2021-11-08 23:15:12', false),
        (2, timestamp '2021-11-08 23:15:30', true),
        (3, timestamp '2021-10-07 04:06:08', false),
        (3, timestamp '2021-10-07 07:47:43', true),
        (3, timestamp '2021-10-07 07:49:56', false),
        (3, timestamp '2021-10-07 07:51:35', false),
        (8, timestamp '2021-10-06 15:36:46', false),
        (8, timestamp '2021-10-06 15:37:12', false),
        (9, timestamp '2021-10-07 07:13:27', false),
        (9, timestamp '2021-10-07 07:15:07', true),
        (9, timestamp '2021-10-07 07:17:33', false),
        (10, timestamp '2021-10-06 14:03:57', true),
        (10, timestamp '2021-10-06 14:10:45', false)
)

SELECT id,
    min_by(fact, Timestamp) first_fact,
    min(Timestamp) first_iter,
    max_by(fact, Timestamp) last_fact,
    max(Timestamp) last_iter,
    sum(changed) chang_in_fact,
    count(*) as iter
FROM(
        SELECT id,
            Timestamp,
            Fact,
            case
                when prev_fact != fact then 1 else 0
            end as changed
        FROM(
                SELECT *,
                    lag(fact) over (
                        partition by id
                        order by timestamp
                    ) as prev_fact
                FROM dataset
            )
    )
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

Output:

| id | first_fact | first_iter | last_fact | last_iter | chang_in_fact | iter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | false | 2021-10-25 11:21:12.000 | false | 2021-10-25 11:21:12.000 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | false | 2021-10-14 18:49:25.000 | true | 2021-11-08 23:15:30.000 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | false | 2021-10-07 04:06:08.000 | false | 2021-10-07 07:51:35.000 | 2 | 4 |
| 8 | false | 2021-10-06 15:36:46.000 | false | 2021-10-06 15:37:12.000 | 0 | 2 |
| 9 | false | 2021-10-07 07:13:27.000 | false | 2021-10-07 07:17:33.000 | 2 | 3 |
| 10 | true | 2021-10-06 14:03:57.000 | false | 2021-10-06 14:10:45.000 | 1 | 2 |